# Good way to abstract 3rd party javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, prototypal-inheritance

Trying to decide a better way of abstracting a 3rd party javascript API, specifically Google Maps API objects.

My first attempt was something like this:

```
nmap.Polygon = function () {
};

nmap.Polygon.prototype = new google.maps.Polygon();
```

This looks good until I try to act on the object with other parts of the Google Maps API. For example:

```
var poly = new nmap.Polygon(options);
poly.setMap(googleMapObject);
```

This fails silently.

Is my only other option to go with a composition pattern?
IE:

```
var Polygon = function(){
  this.realPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon();
}
```

Comment: Just 2cents, but I like using composition pattern when we want to restrict the interface or redefine it in some way.  We use prototype only with our framework code, so I don't have experience to say why it breaks down on 3rd party APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a common abstraction for mapping APIs you should check out Mapstraction. Supports Google Maps v3 as well as about 15 other providers.

http://mapstraction.com/

Comment: Saw that out there, but at this time don't want to add the conceptual "weight" that I perceive that project to bring.